# ruby google-api-client storage slow upload speed

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am consuming the ruby google-api-client v0.9.pre1, which I have recently upgraded from v0.7.1.

I have been aware that the upload time of my files from my Rails server using the ruby library was slow.  However, I was uploading file by file instead of batching and I assumed this added some time.  When I uplifted to 0.9.pre1 I refactored to the the batch_upload apis and I still have very slow upload times.

The last several attempts have come out to about 0.23 mb/s upload.  It is taking 12-13 seconds to upload 2-3 MB.  My server is hosted on a Google Compute Engine which has access to my Google Storage Bucket.

Can anyone give me an idea why it is so slow to upload files from a server within Google's hosting to Google Storage?  Both AWS and Rackspace blow Google out of the water on storage upload speeds.  I can't help but think I'm missing something.  If not, I may head back in those directions.

Anyone getting better speeds?
Any help or ideas?

Comment: did you try to upload your files using gsutil cp command to see if it's connection issue or api codes? in gsutil use -m to perform a parallel upload: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp